# Android - uniquely identify app

Tags: android, apk

I am currently looking for a possibility to uniquely identify an app throughout the Play Store. When installing Apps only through the Play Store then the package name is unique but what if apps are installed via an alternative market or manually ?

I thought about calculating a hash value for the apk files (which can be found under /data/app or /system/app) but I don't think that this can be done with apps that are located at /data/app-private (without root).

Can anyone tell me how I still can uniquely identify Apps/.apk files.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: The MD5 fingerprint or the signing key would be definative but you can't 'view' those as far as I was aware?http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: An MD5/SHA1 hash would be great but to calculate it I need access to the .apk. This is no problem for "normal" installed apps (/data/app) or system apps but quite a big problem when dealing with private apps in /data/app-private.

Comment: I just found that it is possible to retrieve the signature of the app trough the API. The packagename + version + signature should be quite unique, right ???

Comment: I would think so. If an app has been signed then there exists exactly one keystore that could do sign it with that signature? That combined with the version and package path must make a release build pretty unique.